# Scoping of variable inside a javascript map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
{charts.map( (ch, i) => {
   const tempApiDetails = {...apiDetails};
   tempApiDetails.apiOptions.params = generateParams(ch.dashBoardType, ch.reportType); 
   //above line is to generate params for API call

   <SimpleTable apiOptions={tempApiDetails} />
})}
```

in the above code the `charts` is having 3 items. but all three in the end is having the same `params` which is made for the last chart in the `charts` variable. Can somebody explain me what will be underlying principle for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with scope.

`tempApiDetails` is a **shallow** copy of `apiDetails`.

This means the value of `tempApiDetails.apiOptions` is the same each time it goes around the loop.

Since it is an object, and objects are stored by reference, every time you assign to `apiOptions.params` you are overwriting the `params` of the same object.

You need to make a clone of `apiOptions`.

```
const tempApiDetails = {
    ...apiDetails,
    apiOptions: {...apiDetails.apiOptions}
};
```

And you can do the whole thing in one go:

```
const tempApiDetails = {
    ...apiDetails,
    apiOptions: {
         ...apiDetails.apiOptions,
         params: generateParams(ch.dashBoardType, ch.reportType)
    }
};
```

For complex data structures you might want to look at the [immer library](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/) which will take care of all the cloning for you.

```
const tempApiDetails = produce(apiDetails, draft => {
    draft.apiOptions.params = generateParams(ch.dashBoardType, ch.reportType);
});
```